# Merge two arrays of objects based on nested object key and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, array-merge

I have the following two arrays of objects that I want to merge in one array but based on some nested keys and values inside the nested object of the first array.

Here's what I have right now:

```
const variants = [{
    "name": "Name 1",
    "variationValues": {
        "P00003": "mappedValue1",
        "P00004": "mappedValue4",
    }
}, {
    "name": "Name 2",
    "variationValues": {
        "P00003": "mappedValue2"
    }
}, {
    "name": "Name 3",
    "variationValues": {
        "P00003": "mappedValue3"
    }
}]

const variationAttributes = [{
    "id": "P00003",
    "name": "Variant Name",
    "attributes": [{
        "name": "Variant Name 1",
        "description": "Variant Description 1",
        "attribute": "mappedValue1"
    }, {
        "name": "Variant Name 2",
        "description": "Variant Description 2",
        "attribute": "mappedValue2"
    }, {
        "name": "Variant Name 3",
        "description": "Variant Description 3",
        "attribute": "mappedValue3"
    }, {
        "name": "Variant Name 4",
        "description": "Variant Description 4",
        "attribute": "mappedValue4"
    }]
}, {
    "id": "P00004",
    "name": "Variant Name",
    "attributes": [{
        "name": "Variant Name 4",
        "description": "Variant Description 4",
        "attribute": "mappedValue4"
    }]
}]
```

And here is the expected result:

```
const result = [{
    "variants": [{
        "name": "Name 1",
        "variationValues": {
            "P00003": {
                "name": "Variant Name 1",
                "description": "Variant Description 1",
                "attribute": "mappedValue1"
            },
            "P00004": {
                "name": "Variant Name 4",
                "description": "Variant Description 4",
                "attribute": "mappedValue4"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Name 2",
        "variationValues": {
            "P00003": {
                "name": "Variant Name 2",
                "description": "Variant Description 2",
                "attribute": "mappedValue2"
            }
        }
    }, {
        "name": "Name 3",
        "variationValues": {
            "P00003": {
                "name": "Variant Name 3",
                "description": "Variant Description 3",
                "attribute": "mappedValue3"
            }
        }
    }]
}]
```

Basically it should come down to the following:

1. `variants.variationValues['P00003']` to map to `variationAttributes.id`
2. `variants.variationValues[value]` to map to `variationAttributes.attribute.attribute[value]`

I have tried to start using map and reduce methods, but I'm not even sure what's the best place to start.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any relationship between the two arrays, or you just pair them up in order?

Comment: If it's just by order, you only need `map()`. Map over one of the arrays, and use the index to get the corresponding element in the other array. Then just combine the objects the way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code combines the two arrays like you specified:

```js
// Data

const variants = [{"name":"Name 1","variationValues":{"P00003":"mappedValue1"}},{"name":"Name 2","variationValues":{"P00003":"mappedValue2"}},{"name":"Name 3","variationValues":{"P00003":"mappedValue3"}}];
const variationAttributes = [{"id":"P00003","name":"Variant Name","attributes":[{"name":"Variant Name 1","description":"Variant Description 1","attribute":"mappedValue1"},{"name":"Variant Name 2","description":"Variant Description 2","attribute":"mappedValue2"},{"name":"Variant Name 3","description":"Variant Description 3","attribute":"mappedValue3"}]}];

// Solution code

console.log( getMappedVariants() );

function getMappedVariants() {
    return variants.map((variant) => ({
        ...variant,
        variationValues: mapValuesToAttributes(variant.variationValues),
    }));
}

function mapValuesToAttributes(values) {
    const attributes = {};
    for (const id in values) attributes[id] = findAttribute(id, values[id]);
    return attributes;
}

function findAttribute(id, value) {
    const variation = variationAttributes.find((v) => v.id === id);
    const attribute = variation.attributes.find((a) => a.attribute === value);
    return attribute;
}
```

For the sport of it this could be reduced to one single function, but I would argue that this is the highest level of compression that is still readable.

*Just for the sake of it though, here is the abomination of a single function that has the same result:*

```js
const variants = [{"name":"Name 1","variationValues":{"P00003":"mappedValue1"}},{"name":"Name 2","variationValues":{"P00003":"mappedValue2"}},{"name":"Name 3","variationValues":{"P00003":"mappedValue3"}}];
const variationAttributes = [{"id":"P00003","name":"Variant Name","attributes":[{"name":"Variant Name 1","description":"Variant Description 1","attribute":"mappedValue1"},{"name":"Variant Name 2","description":"Variant Description 2","attribute":"mappedValue2"},{"name":"Variant Name 3","description":"Variant Description 3","attribute":"mappedValue3"}]}];

const getMappedVariants = () =>
    variants.map((variant) => ({
        ...variant,
        variationValues: Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(variant.variationValues).map(([id, value]) => [
                id,
                variationAttributes
                    .find((v) => v.id === id)
                    ?.attributes?.find?.((a) => a.attribute === value),
            ])
        ),
    }));

console.log(getMappedVariants());
```

Answer (score 1):

this way:

```js
const variants = 
  [ { name: 'Name 1', variationValues: { P00003: 'mappedValue1', Pxxxxx: 'mappedxxxxx', } } 
  , { name: 'Name 2', variationValues: { P00003: 'mappedValue2' } } 
  , { name: 'Name 3', variationValues: { P00003: 'mappedValue3' } } 
  ] 
const variationAttributes = 
  [ { id: 'P00003'
    , name: 'Variant Name'
    , attributes: 
      [ { name: 'Variant Name 1', description: 'Variant Description 1', attribute: 'mappedValue1' } 
      , { name: 'Variant Name 2', description: 'Variant Description 2', attribute: 'mappedValue2' } 
      , { name: 'Variant Name 3', description: 'Variant Description 3', attribute: 'mappedValue3' } 
    ] } 
  , { id: 'Pxxxxx'
    , name: 'Variant Name XXXXX'
    , attributes: 
      [ { name: 'Variant Name XXXXX', description: 'Variant Description XXXXX', attribute: 'mappedxxxxx' } 
    ] } 
  ] 


const result = [{}]

result[0].variants = variants.map(({name,variationValues})=>
  {
  let obj = { name, variationValues:{} }

  Object.entries(variationValues).forEach(([k,v]) => {
    let attr = variationAttributes.find(x=> x.id===k ).attributes.find(y=>y.attribute===v )
    obj.variationValues[k] = {...attr }
  })
  return ( obj )
  })

console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: This solution only works if a variant has exactly one attribute. In the provided data this is always the case, but OP might want to add multiple attributes per variation. (That might be my own invalid assumption, but that's a behavioral difference worth considering).

Comment: Yes, there can be different attributes per variations, thanks @soimon

Comment: @YuriyBoev in this case it means that your question was asked incorrectly. I would just have a slight modification in my code to do, to meet multiple attributes. Next time please ask your question properly

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I can see why it wasn't clear enough. I have updated the example.

Comment: @YuriyBoev Yes, this is what I anticipated in correcting my answer, but it looks like you ignored it

Comment: Your solution works as well and I have already upvoted it but I don't have enough reputation for it to show. Not sure what else should I do really, it's my first question here.